# how to create custom and shared rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I have a `v1/queues/index.rabl` like:

```
collection @queues
extends "v1/queues/show"
```

But I want to have a template for successful response which can embed with queue info, like

```
{
  "ok":true,
  "data":[@queues' info] (it can be other info too, like @stack info)
}
```

I am thinking about:

```
def index
  @queues = Queue.all
  render 'shared/success',locals: { url: 'v1/queues/index', data: @queues }
end
```

then create a `share/success.rabl` like:

```
node(:ok) { true }
child(:data) do
  extend("v1/queues/index",:object =>data)
end
```

So in every action, I just need pass the path of the rabl file `v1/queues/index` and instance variable to the shared template `shared/success`. Is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

To create shared rabl, you can use `inheritence` (`extends`) like this:

```
extends 'path/to/shared/rabl'
```

You can `extend` a rabl from inside any other `rabl` using the above syntax.

See [this](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#inheritance) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I didn't explain clearly. I updated my post,could you please view again?